# Where to put tefilin

Tags: tefilin, tefilla, hair

Do you put the front of your tefilin at hairline or do you put the back on it

Answer (score 6):

The poskim are very clear that the entire box must be above the hairline (or where the hairline used to be). See, for example, [Mishnah Berurah 27:33](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&pgnum=74).

Comment: I up voted it for your Icon pic (;

Comment: Glad someone noticed :)